# why is the print statement on "total bones" not running?

Tags: python-3.x

*Im trying to get the print statement to run without it having to run each time the "bones" iteration runs. it should be after the two guesses have been made.*

### [ ]Complete Foot Bones Quiz

```
foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform",
              "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]



def foot_bones_quiz(guess, answer):
        total_bones = 0 
        for bones in answer:
            total_bones += bones.count(bones)
            if guess.lower() == bones.lower():
                return True      
            else:
                pass
        return False
        **print("Total number of identified bones: ", total_bones)**
        
        
    
    guess = 0 
    while guess  < 2:
        guess = guess + 1
        user_guess = input("Enter a bone: ")
        print("Is ", user_guess.lower(), " a foot bone?", foot_bones_quiz(user_guess, foot_bones))
     
    print("Bye, Thanks for your answers.")
```

Comment: ignore the asterisks. for emphasis only.

Comment: this part of the code never executes. the function `return`s in the line right above it. you could put the print statement in the line right above the `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform",
          "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]

# Declare total as global variable rather than in the loop, as we are calling this loop twice, and this will not store the count from previous loop iteration
total_bones = 0

def foot_bones_quiz(guess, answer):
    global total_bones
    for bones in answer:

        # First bones is a string, so bones.count(bones) is just giving 1 all the time, so you have to increase the count, only when a bone is actually identified

        if guess.lower() == bones.lower():
            total_bones += bones.count(bones)
            return True      
        else:
            pass
    return False




guess = 0 
while guess  < 2:
    guess = guess + 1
    user_guess = input("Enter a bone: ")
    print("Is ", user_guess.lower(), " a foot bone?", foot_bones_quiz(user_guess, foot_bones))

print("Bye, Thanks for your answers.")

# Now we actually print, how many guesses were correct out of the 2 made
print("Total number of identified bones: ", total_bones)
```

Tested it on Ubuntu, python 3.6, attaching the screen shots as well.

[image]